# Convert DrawingImage to System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm trying to convert a `System.Windows.Media.DrawingImage` to a `System.Drawing.Image` object.

I've searched up and down but can't seem to find a match for this conversion.
Is it possible to convert between these types?

Thank you

Comment: I couldn't find anything directly, nor do I know much of the topic, but some quick googling suggests that you can convert to a BitmapSource which you can then convert to an Image. Whether practical or not I couldn't say, hence the comment.

Comment: In [How to convert System.Drawing.image to System.Windows.Media.BitmapImage?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aad606b1-3f64-4314-a552-370afd361926/how-to-convert-systemdrawingimage-to-systemwindowsmediabitmapimage?forum=wpf), 
Avatar of Yuri Usenko
Yuri Usenko posted an answer for the reverse operation.

Comment: Note that you can't directly convert a DrawingImage, because it is not a bitmap. So you would have to convert to BitmapSource first, then from BitmapSource to System.Drawing.Bitmap. Search StackOverflow for the second conversion.

Comment: Thank you @Clemens, I was able to modify the example in the link you sent to work to my needs. Appreciate it.